# Compare XPS and PDF, which will be the future standard?

Tags: pdf, xps, xpsdocument

Microsoft proposed XPS, how its status compared to PDF? Is there any advantage of XPS over pdf?

Answer (score 1):

XPS has almost no support outside of Microsoft Office apps. It is difficult to even view an XPS file on a non-Windows machine. PDF is supported everywhere (it's supported by OS X and iOS natively, even!), there are many PDF viewers and generators originating from multiple vendors, and the format overall has clearly retained its title as the de facto standard.